# Issue when trying to make some elements one line

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm making a bar with some fields, I want it to looks like this:
[image]

But yet it looks like this:
[image]

As you can see, there are some problems

- The button is not on the same line
- Elements are not vertically aligned (the text is a bit higher than the serch bar)

I'm using `Twitter Bootstrap` and some `CSS`, I provide you a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/WHIPNb5jtGp8nPyZaR7X?p=preview) if you want to test the code (don't forget to put Plunker view in full screen or it won't show correclty).

Can you help me fix these problems?

*PS: Language is french, I can translate if necessary :)*

---

**HTML code**

```
<hr/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <span class="text-standard-bold">MON STATUT : </span>
        <span class="statut">Administrateur</span>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group col-md-3 recherche">
        <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Rechercher un compte ..."/><br/>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-nouveau">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
            <span class=""> AJOUTER UN UTILISATEUR</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
<hr/>
```

---

**CSS CODE**

```
* {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.statut {
    font-size: 16px;
}

.recherche .input-group-addon {
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #004392;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.recherche .input-group-addon:hover {
    color: #fdb813;
}

.recherche .form-control, .input-group-addon {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #004392;
}

.text-standard {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: rgb(1, 70, 148);
}

.text-standard-bold {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: rgb(1, 70, 148);
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: it's showing in one line..you want that on every resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having together the `.input-group` and `.col-md-3` class with break the `.col-md-3` class. I would suggest to have them seperately. This will ensure that it will work in all screen sizes, e.g. when `col-sm-*` and `col-xs-*` are activated.

Also, for the vertical align issue, you can use the `.form-control-static` which has the same padding with textboxes and buttons.

```
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <p class="form-control-static">
            <span class="text-standard-bold">MON STATUT : </span>
            <span class="statut">Administrateur</span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="input-group recherche">
            <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Rechercher un compte ..."><br>
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-nouveau">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
            <span class=""> AJOUTER UN UTILISATEUR</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
<hr />
```

Here is a working demo: http://www.bootply.com/MyKe33IrUu

Comment: Thanks, it solves my problem! As a rule, you think it is always better to separate `col-md-*` and other classes (like you did in your answer)?

Comment: Yes, I follow that as a general rule. This will prevent such cases of breaking the grid but also the HTML is more maintenable.

Answer (score 0):

`input-group` class is `float:none`. if we change it it will work

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <span class="text-standard-bold">MON STATUT : </span>
        <span class="statut">Administrateur</span>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group col-md-3 recherche" style="float:left;">
        <input type="search" class="form-control" ng-model="cc.search" placeholder="Rechercher un compte ..."/><br/>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        </span>
    </div>

    <!-- Nouveau compte -->
    <div class="col-md-3 pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-nouveau" ng-click="cc.modeCreation = !cc.modeCreation">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
            <span class=""> AJOUTER UN UTILISATEUR</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
<hr/>
   <style>
    * {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.statut {
    font-size: 16px;
}

.recherche .input-group-addon {
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #004392;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.recherche .input-group-addon:hover {
    color: #fdb813;
}

.recherche .form-control, .input-group-addon {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #004392;
}

.text-standard {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: rgb(1, 70, 148);
}

.text-standard-bold {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: rgb(1, 70, 148);
    font-weight: bold;
}
   </style>
```

Comment: It is not a good idea to hardcode the style like that. I would suggest to have the classes in seperate divs, e.g. `<div class="col-md-3"><div class="input-group recherche">`.

Comment: Then use .recherche{float:left} in your stylesheet. it will overwrite float:none of .input-group

Comment: Thanks, but there is still the problem of alignment: `MON STATUT`, `search field` and the `button` are not horizontally aligned